# I make a button base on a state, but how to make them listen to different event in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently working on a small project
I rendered a button base on a state like these two images,
[edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stsiw.png)
[save change button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7geAT.png)

here is my code: but everytime when I click on the edit button it will automatically run the submit button too and the isEdit state can never change to true, like this, [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epAQt.png), please let me know how to solve it. thanks!

```
  const [isEdit, setIsEdit] = useState(true)

  return(
    ...
    {isEdit ? (
          <button
            className="btn btn--fill-primary"
            type="submit"
            disabled={isLoading}
            onSubmit={() => {
              console.log("submit")
              setIsEdit(false)
            }}
          >
            save change
          </button>
        ) : (
          <button
            className="btn btn--fill-black"
            type="button"
            disabled={isLoading}
            onClick={() => {
              console.log("click")
              setIsEdit(true)
            }}
          >
        edit
      </button>
    )}
  )
```

at first I render the button like this:

```
<button
  className={`btn btn--fill-${isEdit ? "primary" : "black"}`}
  type={isEdit ? "submit" : "button"}
  disabled={isLoading}
  onClick={(e) => {
    if (isEdit) {
        console.log('submit')
        setIsEdit(false)
    }

    if (!isEdit) {
        console.log('click')
        setIsEdit(true)
    }
>
    {isEdit ? "save change" : "edit"}
</button>
```

Comment: Can you please also tell what you're trying to achieve like what *should* be the expected behavior

Comment: Hi. Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support). It seems to be working fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-4pi63c?file=App.tsx

Comment: Hi @AMunim, thanks for the reply and sorry for the inconvenience, first time asking question here
I made a example as below link,
[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-udu7zy?file=App.tsx)
what i want to achieve is a button that can control the disablilty of input field, when isEdit is false the button just set isEdit to true, when isEdit is true the button will submit the form to database and update the information.

I think it's becoz when I setIsEdit it trigger the re-render?

Comment: Hi @vighnesh153, sorry I made a example here [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-udu7zy?file=App.tsx). Your's work fine! is it because you make two button as one component?

Comment: This is strange. The edit button is causing the form to be submitted even though `type=button` has been added to it. As a workaround, you can add `e.preventDefault();` at the top of `handleClick` as well. Meanwhile, let me investigate more.

Comment: Created a [bug](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/25930) on react's github page and unfortunately this is expected. To resolve this, you will have to add `key` properties to the buttons, as suggested on the bug.

Comment: read the report and added the key properties, bug still exist. Finally I change the edit button to a div to solve this now